# Ruby on Rails - bootstrap_form gem, labels showing twice

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rubygems

I have recently tried using the gem "bootstrap_form" and everything works except for the fact that my labels are being displayed twice in the pic [image]below on every form in my app. Can anyone help me out here? I was able to fix it by going into the the application.css file and manually putting in some CSS to display:none one of them, but I imagine that is not the purpose of the gem.

```
<%= form_with(model: provider, local: true) do |form| %>
  <% if provider.errors.any? %>
    <div id="error_explanation">
      <h2><%= pluralize(provider.errors.count, "error") %> prohibited this provider from being saved:</h2>

      <ul>
      <% provider.errors.full_messages.each do |message| %>
        <li><%= message %></li>
      <% end %>
      </ul>
    </div>
  <% end %>

  <%= bootstrap_form_for @provider do |f| %>
    <div class="field">
      <%= f.label :name %>
      <%= f.text_field :name, id: :provider_name %>
    </div>

    <div class="actions">
      <%= f.submit %>
    </div>  
  <% end %>
<% end %>
```

Comment: Try removing this label `<%= f.label :name %>`.

Comment: this fixed it, thanks!

Comment: put answer in an answer and i will give you credit for answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just remove the `<%= f.label :name %>` because `text_field` is adding a label as well.

```
<%= bootstrap_form_for @provider do |f| %>
  <div class="field">
    <%= f.text_field :name, id: :provider_name %>
  </div>

  <div class="actions">
    <%= f.submit %>
  </div>  
<% end %>
```